# How to update the whole object of pinia store from form by id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vuejs3, pinia

Please, help me! I've spent a lot of time tring to build vuejs form which adds and updates pinia store Item by it's id, but id doesn't work. Sorry for describing the problem in simple terms and they may be unprofessional.

Assume I have pinia store which contains Items. Each Item is an Object with 3 properties: id, title, content.

I want to develop AddEditView which allows me to add Item in Pinia store of update it depending on route parameters (the code is below).

AddEditView defines the url parameter - id (if any) and passes it on to the child component called Form.

Teh Form component assigns Item from the store to storeObject if id is in props or it assigns it Object with ref('') for id, title, content.

The Form components has child component called FormFields which gets storeObject. Also it passes buttons through slot into child FormFields.

The FormFields component has two child fields: InputField and TextareaField. InputField gets the title of Item by itemTitle property. TextareaField gets ItemContent.

Each child field are in code below.

The scheme of components:

```
AddEditView (get route parameters) -> Form (buttons) -> FormFields (fields) -> InputField and TextareaField
```

The code:

*useItemsStore.js*

```
import { ref, unref, computed, toRaw, markRaw, toRefs } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useSecondTrainStore = defineStore('useSecondTrainStore', () => {

const Items = ref([
    {
        id: 'id0',
        title: 'Title0',
        content: 'Content0'
    },
    {
        id: 'id1',
        title: 'Title1',
        content: 'Content1'
    },
    {
        id: 'id2',
        title: 'Title2',
        content: 'Content2'
    },
])

const getItem = computed(() => {
    return(id) => {
        let item = Items.value.find(item => item.id === id)
        return toRefs(item)
    }
})

function addItem(newItemContent){
    let id = new Date().getTime().toString()
    let convertedObject = {};
    for (const key in newItemContent) {
        convertedObject[key] = newItemContent[key].value;
    }
    convertedObject.id = id
    Items.value.unshift(convertedObject)
}

function updateItem(id, newItemContent){
    let index = Items.value.findIndex(item => item.id === id)
    let item = Items.value[index]

    let convertedObject = {};
    for (const key in newItemContent) {
        convertedObject[key] = newItemContent[key].value;
    }
    item = convertedObject
}


return {Items, getItem, addItem, updateItem }

})

// There are three methods in Store:
// - .getItem(id): it should get plain Object of Items with ref properties (i use toRefs);
// - .addItem(newObject): it should append new Item to Items;
// - .updateItem(id, newObject): it should update Item by it's id. It converts newItemContent with refs to Object.
```

*AddEditView.vue*

```
<script setup>
import {computed} from 'vue'
import Form from '@/components/FormComponent/Form.vue'
import {useRoute} from 'vue-router'
const route = useRoute()

const itemId = computed(() => {
    return route.params.id
})
</script>
<template>

    <Form
    :itemId = itemId
    />

</template>
```

Form.vue

```
<script setup>
import {ref, computed} from 'vue'
import FormFields from '@/components/FormComponent/FormFields.vue'
import {useItemsStore} from '@/stores/Store/useItemsStore.js'
const trainStore = useSecondTrainStore()

const props = defineProps({
    itemId: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
})

const storeObject = computed(() => {
    if(props.itemId.length){
        let item = trainStore.getItem(props.itemId)
        return item
    }else{
        return {
            id: ref(''),
            title: ref(''),
            content: ref('')
        }
    }
})

const handleSave = () => {
    trainStore.updateItem(props.itemId, storeObject.value)
}

const handleAdd = () => {
    trainStore.addItem(storeObject.value)
}
</script>
<template>
    <FormFields
        :itemObject = storeObject
    >



        <template v-slot:buttons>
            <div class="buttons mt-5">
                <button class="button is-primary">Cancel</button>
                <button
                    @click="handleSave"
                    v-if="itemId"
                    class="button is-danger"
                >
                    Save
                </button>
                <button v-else
                    @click="handleAdd"
                    class="button is-danger"
                >
                    Add New Item
                </button>
            </div>
        </template>
    </FormFields>


    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in trainStore.Items">
            <p class="title">{{ item.title }} {{ item.id }}</p>
            <p>{{ item.content }}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

*FormFields.vue*

```
<script setup>
import Textfield from '@/components/FormComponent/Textfield.vue'
import Inputfield from '@/components/FormComponent/Inputfield.vue'


const props = defineProps({
    itemObject: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
})

</script>
<template>
    <span>itemObject.title = {{ props.itemObject }}</span>
    <hr>
    <div class="form">
        <Inputfield
        :itemTitle = itemObject.title
        />

        <Textfield
        :itemContent = itemObject.content
        />
    </div>
    <div class="field is-grouped is-grouped-right">
        <div class="control">
            <slot name="buttons" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

*InputField.vue*

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    itemTitle: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
})
const emit = defineEmits(['update:itemTitle'])

</script>
<template>
    <div class="form">
        {{ itemTitle }}
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Title</label>
            <div class="control">
                <input
                    :value = "itemTitle.value"
                    @input="$emit('update:itemTitle', $event.target.value)"
                    class="input"
                    placeholder="Text input"
                    type="text"
                >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

*Textarea.vue*

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    itemContent: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
})
const emit = defineEmits(['update:itemContent'])

</script>
<template>
    <div class="form">
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Content</label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea
                    :value = "itemContent.value"
                    @input="$emit('update:itemContent', $event.target.value)"
                    class="textarea"
                    placeholder="Text input"
                    type="text"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

*router/index.js*

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import FormView from'@/views/FormView.vue'
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [   
    {
      path: '/addEdit/:id?',
      name: 'add-edit',
      component: FormView
    }
  ]
})

export default router
```

---

The problem is that neither the add method nor the update work. I have tried different types of object properties but nothing happens. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

*Sorry for the long description and for such nesting of components into each other. But I need such a structure for a more complex project, in which there can be, for example, a lot of Input Fields and in each parent Form there can be a lot of FormFields to update several StoreObjects.*